# Can you use bread flour that is 2 months past the best use by date?

Tags: baking, food-safety, flour

I've got some bread flour that has been in the refrigerator that has a best use date of Sept. 2015, and it's now Nov. 2015, is it okay to still bake with it?

Comment: I would be way more worried on possible effects of humidity from the fridge than a best-by date, which means only that it will be in prime condition until then, not that it suddenly spoils after that. My recommendation: Happy baking!

Comment: Your nose knows. The smell of rancidity is distinctive and your body is biologically primed to spot it and avoid it. If it smells bad, don't use it. But if it's been in the fridge and is only 2 months past the best-use date, I can almost guarantee that it's fine. The "Best by" date is almost meaningless, especially for something like refined flour.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of "best used by" date, on most products, is an indicator of freshness, as opposed to safety.  Of course, things like temperature, light...storage conditions in general, also impact product quality.  So there are several variables to consider.  As pointed out above, give it a look, give it a smell...if it passes those tests give it a try.